# How to compare the same db at new moments in time

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, comparison, delphi-xe2

By developing client server applications in Delphi + SQL Server I continuously face the problem to have an exact report of what an action caused on db.

A simple example is:

1. BEFORE: start "capturing" the DB
2. user changes a value in an editbox
3. the user presses a "save" button
4. AFTER: stop "capturing" the DB

I would like to have a tool that compares the before and after status (I manually capture the `BEFORE` and `AFTER` status).

I googled for this kind of tools but all I found are tools for doing data or schema comparison between more datasources.

Thanks.

Comment: What about [`transaction log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190925(v=sql.105).aspx) ? Or just making a log table.

Comment: once i remember i saw a demo of a product that allwoed to do what i ask, unfortunately i cannot recall which product it is. it was amazing.

Comment: If you want to catch all changes to a Sql Server db, including changes not made by your app, you could set up triggers on the db tables to log the changes, and there are products which will help you set up the triggers.  OTOH, if you're only interested in changes made by your app, and it only updates one row at a time, it's not too difficult to write your own logging facility.

Comment: @MartynA imagine this scenario: reverse engineering. It is much helpful to see what happens if a tool tells me, insteed than writing log code on a legacy app.

Comment: Ok, well you didn't mention reverse engineering initially.  Anyway, SO isn't really the place to get product recommendations: ime, far and away the best place to ask for those is in the delphi.thirdpartytools.general section of the EMBA newsgroups.

Comment: @MartynA you are right but EDN newsgroup are sleepy.

Comment: I was thinking you could maybe do what you want by doing a stack trace from the point that a Delphi dataset saves a change to the db back to the component click or action which invoked it, and had a quick google.  Could this be the tool you were recalling?  http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/dbmonitor.html

Answer (score 1):

The following is an extract for an application we have.  This code is in a BeforePost event handler that is linked to all of the Dataset components in the application.  This linking is done using code as there are a lot of datasets.  This doesn't actually log the changes (just lists the fields) but it should be simple enough to change to meet your objective.  I don't know if this is exactly right for what you are trying to achieve since you ask for a tool but it would be an effective way of creating a report of all changes

```
  CurrentReport := Format('Table %s modified', [DataSet.Name]);
  for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    XField := DataSet.Fields[i];
    if (XField.FieldKind = fkData) and (XField.Value <> XField.OldValue) then
    begin
      CurrentReport := CurrentReport + Format(', %s changed', [XField.FieldName])
    end;
  end;
```

Note that our code collects a report but only logs it after the post has been successfully completed

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the code, it is a good idea to use it in an app, as i wrote in a comment above i need to reverse engineer a complex app, this is why a tool would help me a lot.